# Timber upgrade 1.19 site.language deprecated?

Tags: timber, wpml

I notice since Timber version 1.19, the `{% if site.language == ‘pt-PT’ %}` stopped working. I have WPML.

When I downgrade to 1.18.2, it’s working.

I use this workaround in my staging site:

`{% if site.link == 'https://mywebsite.com' %}`

but I would prefer a better alternative.

I’m planning to upgrade Timber, but step by step.